# Download version file of SharePoint office 365

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, token, httpwebrequest

I tried to download previous version files of SharePoint using c#. I have used [This article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/87156) as reference. The link is working file with chrome. Now when I tried the URL on c# to download the file part by part, it is giving me **The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.** error.

I have even provided access token using to header of the function.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            WebHeaderCollection header = new WebHeaderCollection();
            request.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, $"Bearer {token}");
            request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
```

Here,
uri is similar to the address: http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_vti_history/512/Documents/Book1.xlsx

How can I download the previous version file using c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my test code for your reference.

```
var login = "user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
            var password = "Password";

            var securePassword = new SecureString();

            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

            string webUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee";
            string requestUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee/_vti_history/512/MyDoc2/testdata.xlsx";
            Uri uri = new Uri(requestUrl);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
            request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = onlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(new Uri(webUrl), true);  // SPO requires cookie authentication
            request.Headers["X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED"] = "f";  // disable interactive forms-based auth            
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, How can i get stream without username and password ?

Comment: is there any way to do it with access token?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a complete example to download a file from a SharePoint site using a Client Id and Client Secret.

Main problems were encountered:

1. Getting an access token that would actually be accepted. It was pretty easy to get an access token, but trying to use it to download a file would result in a 401 with a message `invalid_client`.

These are the authUrls that didn't work. The value of `x` tried was both the tenantId (e.g. a guid) or the tenantDomain (e.g. company.com). An access token would be returned, but the returned resource was always for Microsoft Graph (`00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`).

```
String authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + x + "/oauth2/token";
String authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + x + "/oauth2/v2.0/token";
String authUrl = "https://login.windows.net/" + x + "/oauth2/token";
String authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
```

The authUrl that actually worked was:

```
String authUrl = "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/" + tenantId + "/tokens/OAuth/2";
```

2. The second problem was using direct URL to download the file,
   e.g. `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/Data.xlsx`

Apparently direct urls don't work. The theory is that an internal server Redirect strips out the access token from the request headers. Thus, the file has to be downloaded using either:

a) `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared Documents/FileName.xlsx')/$value`

The `/$value` at the end says to download the actual binary data. If it is omitted, then an XML file is downloaded with properties about the file (`created date`, `modified date`, `length`, etc).

or

b) `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=/Shared Documents/FileName.xlsx`

Note: if option a) is used, then any single quotes in the 'FileName' have to be replaced with two single quotes in a row. More can be read about the escaping issue here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154590/getfilebyserverrelativeurl-fails-when-the-filename-contains-a-quote

3. Forgetting to set:
   `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

This results in a message something like, the connection was forcibly closed.

4. Make sure that the `-DisableCustomAppAuthentication` is `false`. This can be set through PowerShell.

   `PS> install-module -name "PnP.PowerShell"`

   `PS> Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com"`

   `PS> Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false`

Note: I saw a lot of code where headers were set, such as:

```
req.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
req.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
req.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
req.Headers.Add("Use-Agent", "Other");
```

None of these headers were required for ClientId/ClientSecret authentication. However, `"X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED"` is required when using legacy `SharePointOnlineCredentials`.

Useful links:

- https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/connect-pnponline-with-appid-and-appsecret.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

The code below provides a few different approaches for getting the access token and downloading a file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace SharePointDemo {

public class Program {

    const String SharePointPrincipal = "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000";

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // required.

        // Replace these 6 values:
        Uri url = new Uri("https://tenant.sharepoint.com"); // with or without an ending '/' both work
        String clientId = "... guid ...";
        String clientSecret = "... generated using the SharePoint AppRegNew.aspx ..."; // see useful links above
        String tenantId = "... guid ..."; // aka realm. Can be found in the SharePoint admin site settings, or by using GetTenantId(url);
        String fileRelativeUrl = "/Shared Documents/Data.xlsx";
        String filename = @"C:\temp\Data.xlsx"; // local file name
        
        String access_token_key = "access_token"; // variable name in headers to look for in authUrl's response.
        Uri fileUrl = new Uri(url.ToString() + "_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=" + fileRelativeUrl);
        //Uri fileUrl = new Uri(url.ToString() + "_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + fileRelativeUrl.Replace("'", "''") + "')/$value"); // also works

        String clientIdPrincipal = clientId + "@" + tenantId;
        String resource = SharePointPrincipal + "/" + url.Host + "@" + tenantId;

        // Note: a 'scope' parameter is not required for this authUrl, but 'resource' is required.
        String authUrl = "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/" + tenantId + "/tokens/OAuth/2";
        String content = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<username>&client_secret=<password>&resource=<resource>";
        content = content.Replace("<username>", clientIdPrincipal);
        content = content.Replace("<password>", clientSecret);
        content = content.Replace("<resource>", resource);

        AuthResult result = GetAuthResult(authUrl, content, access_token_key);
        String accessToken = result.access_token;
        DownloadFile1(fileUrl, accessToken, filename); // pick whichever DownloadFile method floats your boat
    }

    private static AuthResult GetAuthResult(String authUrl, String content, String access_token_key = "access_token", int timeoutSeconds = 10) {
        HttpContent data = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        using (data) {
            using (HttpClient c = new HttpClient()) {
                c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds);
                using (HttpResponseMessage res = c.PostAsync(authUrl, data).Result) {
                    HttpStatusCode code = res.StatusCode;
                    String message = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    if (code == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        return ParseMessage(message, access_token_key);

                    throw new Exception("Auth failed. Status code: " + code + " Message: " + message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // alternative way using HttpWebRequest
    private static AuthResult GetAuthResult2(String authUrl, String content, String access_token_key = "access_token", int timeoutSeconds = 10) {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(authUrl);
        req.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.None;
        req.ContentLength = content.Length;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Timeout = timeoutSeconds * 1000;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)) {
            sw.Write(content);
            sw.Close();
        }

        using (WebResponse res = req.GetResponse()) {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII)) {
                String message = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return ParseMessage(message, access_token_key);
            }
        }
    }

    // this could also be done using a Json library
    private static AuthResult ParseMessage(String message, String access_token_key) {
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        char[] trimChars = new [] { '{', '"', '}' };
        String[] arr = message.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
            String t = arr[i];
            int x = t.IndexOf(':');
            if (x < 0)
                continue;
            String varName = t.Substring(0, x).Trim(trimChars);
            String value = t.Substring(x + 1).Trim(trimChars);
            ht[varName] = value;
        }

        String accessToken = (String) ht[access_token_key];
        if (accessToken == null)
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Could not find '{0}' in response message: ", access_token_key) + message);

        AuthResult result = new AuthResult();
        result.access_token = accessToken;
        result.resource = (String) ht["resource"];
        result.token_type = (String) ht["token_type"];
        int val = 0;
        if (int.TryParse((String) ht["expires_in"], out val)) result.expires_in = val;
        if (int.TryParse((String) ht["expires_on"], out val))
            result.expires_on = val;
        else
            result.expires_on = (int) (DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(result.expires_in) - AuthResult.EPOCH).TotalSeconds;

        if (int.TryParse((String) ht["not_before"], out val)) result.not_before = val;
        return result;
    }

    private class AuthResult {
        public static readonly DateTime EPOCH = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        public DateTime NotBefore { get { return EPOCH.AddSeconds(not_before).ToLocalTime(); } }
        public DateTime ExpiresOn { get { return EPOCH.AddSeconds(expires_on).ToLocalTime(); } }

        public int not_before { get; set; }
        public int expires_on { get; set; }
        public String resource { get; set; }

        ///<summary>Indicates the token type value. The only type that the Microsoft identity platform supports is bearer.</summary>
        public String token_type { get; set; }
        ///<summary>The amount of time that an access token is valid (in seconds).</summary>
        public int expires_in { get; set; }
        ///<summary>The access token generated by the authentication server.</summary>
        public String access_token { get; set; }
    }

    public static void DownloadFile1(Uri fileUrl, String accessToken, String filename, int timeoutSeconds = 60) {
        using (var c = new HttpClient()) { // requires reference to System.Net.Http
            c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds);
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage();
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            req.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            req.RequestUri = fileUrl;
            using (HttpResponseMessage res = c.SendAsync(req).Result) {
                if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                    using (Stream s = res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result) {
                        using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
                            s.CopyTo(fs);
                            fs.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    String message = "Error. Server returned status code: " + res.StatusCode + " (" + (int) res.StatusCode + "). Headers: " + res.Headers.ToString();
                    throw new Exception(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // slight variation to DownloadFile1, but basically the same
    public static void DownloadFile2(Uri fileUrl, String accessToken, String filename, int timeoutSeconds = 60) {
        using (var c = new HttpClient()) {
            c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds);
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            using (HttpResponseMessage res = c.GetAsync(fileUrl).Result) {
                if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                    using (Stream s = res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result) {
                        using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
                            s.CopyTo(fs);
                            fs.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    String message = "Error. Server returned status code: " + res.StatusCode + " (" + (int) res.StatusCode + "). Headers: " + res.Headers.ToString();
                    throw new Exception(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DownloadFile3(Uri fileUrl, String accessToken, String filename, int timeoutSeconds = 60) {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(fileUrl);
        //req.ContinueTimeout = ...;
        //req.ReadWriteTimeout = ...;
        req.Timeout = timeoutSeconds * 1000;
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + accessToken);
        req.Method = "GET";
        try {
            using (var res = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse()) {
                using (Stream s = res.GetResponseStream()) {
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
                        s.CopyTo(fs);
                        fs.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ex is WebException) {
                var we = (WebException) ex;
                String headers = we.Response.Headers.ToString();
                throw new WebException(we.Message + " headers: " + headers, we);
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static void DownloadFile4(Uri fileUrl, String accessToken, String filename) {
        using (WebClient c = new WebClient()) {
            c.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            using (Stream s = c.OpenRead(fileUrl)) {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
                    s.CopyTo(fs);
                    fs.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Helper methods, not used:

    ///<summary>
    ///Makes an http request to the site url in order to read the GUID tenant-id (also called the realm) from the response headers.
    ///</summary>
    public static Guid? GetTenantId(Uri siteUrl, int timeoutSeconds = 10) {
        // the code: url = url.TrimEnd('/') + "/_vti_bin/client.svc"; is not needed
        String url = siteUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

        // use HttpClient to avoid Exception when using HttpWebRequest
        using (var c = new HttpClient()) { // requires reference to System.Net.Http
            c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds);
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage();

            // "Bearer " without an access token results in StatusCode = Unauthorized (401) and the response headers contain the tenant-id
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ");
            req.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            req.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
            using (HttpResponseMessage res = c.SendAsync(req).Result) {
                // HttpStatusCode code = res.StatusCode; // typically Unauthorized
                System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpResponseHeaders h = res.Headers;
                foreach (String s in h.GetValues("WWW-Authenticate")) { // should only have one
                    Guid? g = TryGetGuid(s);
                    if (g.HasValue)
                        return g;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Guid? GetTenantId_old(Uri siteUrl, int timeoutSeconds = 10) {
        String url = siteUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        req.Timeout = timeoutSeconds * 1000;
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ";

        String header = null;
        try {
            using (req.GetResponse()) {}
        } catch (WebException e) {
            if (e.Response != null)
                header = e.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"];
        }
        return TryGetGuid(header);
    }

    private static Guid? TryGetGuid(String header) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
            return null;

        const String bearer = "Bearer realm=\"";
        int bearerIndex = header.IndexOf(bearer, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (bearerIndex < 0)
            return null;

        int x1 = bearerIndex + bearer.Length;
        int x2 = header.IndexOf('"', x1 + 1);
        String realm = (x2 < 0 ? header.Substring(x1) : header.Substring(x1, x2 - x1));

        Guid guid;
        if (Guid.TryParse(realm, out guid))
            return guid;

        return null;
    }
}
}
```